# Parse Json content in model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a payment and Payment history models

> Payment History:

```
class PaymentHistory extends Model
{
    public function subscription()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Payment', 'id','payment_id');
    }

}
```

> Payment :

```
class Payment extends Model
    {
        public function PaymentHistory(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PaymentHistory ','id','payment_id');
    }
    
    }
```

I have a json column named as response in Payment History table that i want to return it after decoding json data in model function with each and every row

My query in controller is as follows

```
 $data = User::with('Payment.PaymentHistory')->get();
```

i was trying to do something like this in payment history model:

```
   public function json_response() 
    {
        return json_decode($json, TRUE);
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Caste the JSON column to array in the model class and it'll be automatically converted to an array. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#cast-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add `$casts` for that column in `PaymentHistory` model

```
protected $casts = ['column_name' => 'array'];
```

so no need to manually json encode or decode

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting